# Comparing output to string

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

Need a little more assistance here please I am just a little way from completing my script but can't seem to figure this last piece out.

**Background:**

I need to compare a command output `\\%%A\%B` to a preset "exclusion list" to compare whether or not the process is already running on a different script.
I have a file that stores logs of files locations that had errors copying over.  This log file is parsed and all the file locations are stored (on the fly) into `%%A` and `%%B`.  The exclusion list says which files are already being copied manually based on known issues.  This script needs to skip these files and copy the rest.

**Requirement:**

I need to compare the results of %%A\%%B to \root\path and see if the string matches (before the file). If it does then I need to flag it.

**Code:**

This is what I have so far:

```
cd C:\logs
for /f "tokens=2* delims=\" %%A in (err.log) do (
    if not \\%%A\%%B==%BACKUPDIR% (
        if not \\%%A\%%B==%TEMPLATEPATH%\* (        
            for %%I in %PSTNAMES% do (
                if not "\\%%A\%%B"=="%NASDIR%\%%I PST\"* (
                    echo %NASDIR%\%%I PST\*
                    @echo \\%%A\%%B
                ) else (
                    echo false
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This should give you an idea of what needs to happen
I am also trying to fit in the comparison code:

```
If NOT "%somepath%"=="%somepath:some_exclusion=%" (
    echo continue
) else (
    echo don't continue
)
```

**EXTRA:**

Now the first set of code would work if I just had the paths to work with but because it includes file names the comparison doesn't match up.
So to get this working I guess there are two avenues.

1. Try get the `"%somepath%"=="%somepath:some_exclusion=%"`working
2. Try strip the file name

The issues I am coming across are:

1. `%somepath%` won't work because I can't seem to store `%%A` as a variable like `%var%`
2. I can't seem to stop the path name before the file name.

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to use a wildcard with `if`?

Comment: Add `echo if not \\%%A\%%B==%BACKUPDIR%` just before `if not \\%%A\%%B==%BACKUPDIR%`, `echo if not \\%%A\%%B==%TEMPLATEPATH%\*` just before `if not \\%%A\%%B==%TEMPLATEPATH%\*` etc. to see what is wrong... The `==` invokes simple text comarison, with no possible wildcards

Comment: I was just giving an example as in I need to find \\share\path\anything that matches \\share\path\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to use wildcards with `if`: this won't work.

but instead of

```
if mouse==mouse*
```

you can use

```
echo mousetail | find "mouse" && echo yes || echo no
```

(showed just the basic principle; `findstr` has some useful features, like "start of string": `findstr "^mouse" - see`findstr /?` for more)